# How to avoid printf warnings about types

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, printf

I'm wondering if there is a nice way to avoid gcc to scream about printf types :
'warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 12 has type foo'

This is pretty anoying when you know that you wrote 'typedef int foo' somewhere ...

Of course, I'm not looking for the gcc fix for that ( [-Wformat] ).

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid the warning WITHOUT casting each time of course!

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that you still want to get other warnings... right? But do you want to get valid printf() warnings?

Comment: Can you show us a code example of where you're getting a warning you think is spurious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have `typedef int foo`, gcc shouldn't warn you. If `gcc` *is* warning you, there's a fair chance `foo` really isn't an integer.

Comment: *I* have `typedef int foo`--not because I *know* I wrote it, but because I actually looked--and I can't find a set of command-line switches that will make gcc give me a warning. Of course, it would be warning me that although it expected an int, instead I was giving it an int. There are a blue million possibilities, though. I might have overlooked one or two combinations.

Comment: Yep, posted the question too quickly ... sorry folks, gcc already knows what is good for us :)

Answer (score 0):

This has Undefined Behaviour all over. **Do not use!**

```
char *fmt;
fmt = "%d%f%p%u\n";
printf(fmt, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1); /* fill stack with values */
```